# How to get info from Database according to the id

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am making an App that Adds Groceries to a list , I have a Product class which contains all of it's properties , so I am  trying to get a product from the Database Table according to it's Id and return it ,but it keeps telling me that my app is stopping whenever i call my function , this is my code

```
public Product GetProductById(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Product p=null;
    Cursor cr;
    cr = db.query(PRODUCTS_TABLE, null, PRODUCT_ID+"="+id, null, null, null, null);
    cr.moveToFirst();
    if(!cr.isAfterLast()) {
        p=new Product();
        p.setId(cr.getInt(0));
        p.setName(cr.getString(1));
        p.setQuantity(cr.getInt(2));
        p.setPrice(cr.getDouble(3));
        p.setAllergens(cr.getString(4));
        p.setPurchased(cr.getInt(5));
        p.setImage(cr.getBlob(6));
        p.setPriority(cr.getInt(7));
    }
    return p;
}
```

this code is not working and i don't know where the error is.
here are my Database columns(names and types...):

```
public static final String DB_NAME="db_groceries";
public static final int DB_VER=1;
public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "name";
public static final String PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "quantity";
public static final String PRODUCT_PRICE = "price";
public static final String PRODUCT_ALLERGENS = "allergens";
public static final String PRODUCT_PRIORITY = "priority";
public static final String PRODUCT_ID = "_id";
public static final String PRODUCT_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String PRODUCTS_TABLE = "groceries";
public static final String PRODUCTS_PURCHASED = "purchased";
public static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "create table "
        + PRODUCTS_TABLE + "(" + PRODUCT_ID +
        " integer primary key autoincrement," +
        PRODUCT_NAME + " text not null," +
        PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " integer not null," +
        PRODUCT_PRICE + " real not null," +
        PRODUCT_ALLERGENS + " text not null, " +
        PRODUCTS_PURCHASED + " integer not null, " +
        PRODUCT_IMAGE + " blob," +
        PRODUCT_PRIORITY + " integer not null)";
```

can you figure out where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that you have not instantiated **ourHelper** before calling the GetProductById method.

If you haven't then you would get a null pointer exception similar to :-

```
11-01 19:54:35.925 1420-1420/axtest.axtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{axtest.axtest/axtest.axtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at axtest.axtest.MainActivity.GetProductById(MainActivity.java:134)
        at axtest.axtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To resolve this you need to instantiate ourHelper along the lines of

```
**`ourHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);`**
```

Noting that Databasehelper may be different (you haven't said what the class name is) and also that the signature may also be different (it will be dependent upon the code in the Database helper although frequently the signature is as above).

Otherwise you code works fine. However, it may also be that you have changed the structure of the table but not deleted the database. To rule out this delete the App's data and rerun the App.